# PHP - get main array key search by value into two-level multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `$array` with build:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["woj"]=>
    string(4) "﻿2"
    ["pow"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["gmi"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["rodz_gmi"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Test1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["woj"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["pow"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["gmi"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["rodz_gmi"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "test2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["woj"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["pow"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["gmi"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["rodz_gmi"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "test3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["woj"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["pow"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["gmi"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["rodz_gmi"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Test4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["woj"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["pow"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["gmi"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["rodz_gmi"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Test5"
  }
}
```

and I want to create a php function, which can be search main array key by value (`name`).
Example - search main array key by name: `test3`. Result should be `2`, because second main key of `$array` contain subarray where `name` key = `test3`.

I tied with array_search, but with multidimensional array, this function not work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following for your multi-dimensional array:

```php
function myCustomSearch($data,$searchVal){
     foreach($data as $index => $subArray){
          foreach($subArray as $key=>$value){
               if($value === $searchVal)return $index;
          }
     }
     return null; //return null if not found
}
```

eg use assuming your current array shared in question is stored in `$data`

```php
$resultIndex = myCustomSearch($data,'test3');
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: `$resultIndex = array_search('test3', array_column($arr, 'name'));`